# How does Windows manage authentication keys for Opal drives?

Tags: windows, bitlocker, fde, opal, tcg-opal

I want to use a FIPS certified Opal drive on Windows to implement a system with at least one restricted encrypted partition.  I want to use the band authentication feature of Opal to restrict access to a particular partition to a single service account.  I would like the TPM to seal the band authentication key to that service account.  I have been searching TCG and Microsoft documentation for days now and don't see anything to tell me if this is possible.

Comment: Because of various vulnerabilities found in TCG opal devices AFAIK Bitlocker now does not use the self encryption functionality of TCG opal drives anymore, instead only software/CPU based en/decryption is used. https://www.zdnet.com/article/flaws-in-self-encrypting-ssds-let-attackers-bypass-disk-encryption/

Comment: Regarding how Bitlocker uses the Opal drive I think I'll believe Microsoft. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/encrypted-hard-drive  Also, it is not possible to use an Opal drive without using the internal encryption engine.  ALL blocks on the drive are encrypted, even if you don't enable any of the access control features you CANNOT turn off device encryption.

Comment: Yes TCG Opal devices are always encrypted but you can decide if you use it for Bitlocker or if Bitlocker is added as additional security layer above making the data in the end encrypted twice. For the option to use hardware encryption or not please read this: https://www.technadu.com/bitlocker-to-use-software-encryption-on-windows-10/54907/ Not sure if this is still the case.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  This problem appears to be limited to SSD drives and specifically the ATA and NVMe protocols.  It should not be a problem for hard disks.  However, if Microsoft is defaulting to software encryption on all disks then that would add an unnecessary load for hard disk systems.  Something to look for when we set it up.

Comment: Why do you think that software encryption would cause "unnecessary load" to the hard disk systems? The HDDs write data and the size of the data doesn't change by the encryption. The AES en/decryption is then performed by the CPU and nearly all modern CPU support AES-NI instruction set for performing AES in hardware which is very fast (>1GB/sec) at very low CPU utilization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I'll go with "no, that's not going to work".

First, I'm not sure whether "seal the band authentication key to that service account" is even something that *makes sense* to do with a TPM. The OS has no way of proving to the TPM that a specific user is performing the access, and an administrator could impersonate any other user ID – especially "service account" user IDs that the OS already needs to use without credentials.

Also, the TPM's PCRs are append-only and represent strictly-ordered events, but file access within the OS does not have a guaranteed order – so if the OS tried extending a PCR with the current UID for every file access, it would almost never succeed at arriving at the same PCR value twice.

(Alternatively, the OS could generate e.g. an EFS keypair on the TPM and use its own facilities to make sure only the specific account could access it – this is already very easy with interactive user accounts as there is a TPM-backed CNG key provider – but service accounts *don't* have DPAPI available to them, there's really nothing that could protect their keypairs from being stolen by an administrator armed with mimikatz.)

Moreover, in a multi-user OS, once a hardware device is unlocked, it *remains* unlocked regardless of what happens in the OS. So even if Windows was capable of unlocking a particular Opal drive when a specific account first tried to access it, from that point on it would still remain the OS responsibility to prevent the same drive from being accessed by other users.

In other words, as soon as your service was started there would still be no difference in using a service-specific key, versus using typical OS-wide BitLocker encryption and relying on NTFS file permissions. (If you can't trust the OS to enforce file permissions, would you really trust it to enforce the per-user Opal access restriction?)

Comment: Thanks for this information. You sent me off on another round of chasing documentation.  I understand your point about binding a user identity to a key with the TPM so we can take that idea off the table.  I also see that DPAPI can't be used by a service because DPAPI uses the user's userid and password. Let's assume we are running AD could we have AD hold the key?  Then the system would be as trustworthy as AD.  I'm not sure we can do better than that. We can have the service application signed so that Windows can verify its authenticity before running it.

Comment: Well, if the service doesn't have credentials, it can't authenticate to AD as itself either – it can only use the host's global "machine credentials" (which are available to any service running as 'SYSTEM'), and **AD still has to believe what the OS claims.** (AD does store some secrets, including e.g. "backup keys" used within DPAPI, but ultimately it only knows the credentials it's been given.)

Comment: Well Local System isn't sufficiently restrictive for my application.  Seems I need to create an account specific to this service.  What I need is mandatory access control restricted to a single account.  That should also exclude admin accounts.  Actually the ability to exclude admin accounts is critical.

Comment: As far as I know there is no practical way to exclude admin accounts, unless you virtualize the whole system and use Hyper-V "Shielded VMs" (I think this relies on Secure Boot and TPM attestation). Otherwise they can just change the service configuration to run a different .exe (signed by their "trusted" CA that they just installed).

Comment: They would have to replace the Microsoft roots.

Comment: Why? If your original service isn't signed by Microsoft roots, then the replacement "service" doesn't have to be either.

Comment: Just started reading about Windows Defender Application Control.  Seems we can require everything to be signed.  I haven't gotten far enough to know if the signatures need to verify to the Microsoft roots or not.  If not then we can supply our own.

Answer (score -1):

I'm coming to believe that what Windows is doing is defining only two bands on the Opal drive one for admin and one for user data.  It gives Bitlocker both keys and then proceeds to manage the user data band as a raw volume that can be partitioned however the user likes.  This would mean that there is no way that a user could access the band authentication functions of the drive.  All user access control must be via NTFS.

Comment: Is "band" an OPAL-specific term? (The specs I've found seem to talk about "[out-of-band](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out-of-band) authentication", not "[out of] band-authentication".)

Comment: Yes Opal talks about bands on the device which are contiguous extents of blocks.   Opal uses bands to define access control regions.  You can only access a band if you have the authorization key.  Unfortunately for my purposes, Windows does not give the user access to that level of access control.  Bitlocker takes control of all of the band authentication keys  and then any further access control must be via NTFS.

Comment: AFAIK there are no "bands" in OPAL; it defines ranges. you are completely confused about what OPAL is and how it works. it looks like you think OPAL keys are tokens you use for specific accesses, as if drives were web services or something. OPAL keys can unlock ranges. once unlocked, you are done with the key. OPAL defends ranges from systems that do not posses a key, like a machine in pre-boot authentication state. there is no scenario in which a system knows an OPAL keys and OPAL somehow defends a range which can be/has been unlocked by said key.